# (PY) Upgrading pip and installing json package don't work

Tags: python, json, pip, pycharm, installation

Q1. I entered `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and it answered that regularly worked. But, when I check it again by `pip list`, it was found that the version has been not changed. How can I solve this problem?

[image: image description]

Q2. `pip install json` also doens't work!

[image: image description]

This is PyCharm on Windows 8.1 K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is part of python's standard library.

You don't need to install it, just import json

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: I tried entering `import json` directly on the console, I found that it worked. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I don't know what I wrote wrong but this time import json worked. great thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved the problem of Q1 by deleting pips of the previous version directly and installing its newest version again like the below. :

[image: \Lib\site-packages]

[image: Successfully installed pip-18.0]